# How do I create this shape with some rounded corners in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, shapes, illustrator-effects, corners

I'm using CS6.

I want to create this shape, that is shaped like a backwards L and has some rounded edges on the bottom and then straight edges on the two upper corners.

Whenever I try and google how to round edges of a shape all I get is either drag the corners (which I can't do cos CS6) or use Effects > Round corners which rounds all of them.

How can I create this shape?

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Can't you just [redraw it manually](https://imgur.com/anSWJfh) with the Pen Tool?

Comment: [Round any corner script](http://shspage.com/aijs/en/#roundany) - Download link for the whole pack at the top of the page.

Comment: @BillyKerr That's what I was trying to do, but I have no way to round the bottom left edge like it is on the picture, every solution I've seen rounds everything

Comment: @jm123456 in the example I didn't round any corners, I just drew simple straight lines and curves using the Pen Tool.

Comment: @jm123456, I think you missed my comment above with the script: "Round _any corner_".

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way:

- Create the `L` as a thick stroke and set it to round edges.
- Convert this to a shape via `Object → Path → Outline stroke`.
- Then, create a rectangle and do a pathfinder subtract and remove that part where you need straight corners.

[image]

Comment: But if I convert to a shape I'll lose the vector-ness of the object won't I?

Comment: No, it stays 100% vector, NOT PIXELIZED, you only lose the stroke aspect of it, if you're familiar with what these are. You take a vector line and turn it to a vector shape. Vector-ness preserved.

Comment: Is there a way I can apply an inner stroke to this to give it a different colour on the inside?

Comment: Probably using an offset path, which creates an identical, scaled down shape, inside another shape. Do some research.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**

1. Draw a rectangle and shear it. Copy the same in front and move accordingly. (You will need some measurements if you want both horizontal and vertical *segment* widths equal.)
2. Minus Front
3. Round the corners wherever you need
4. Fill color/gradient/strokes according to requirements

[image]

**Method 2:**

[image]

This is somewhat non-destructive. You can alter things.